# Hardinfo Doesn't display anything in the storage section

Tags: hardware, monitor, storage

[image]I installed Hardinfo on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop.  The "storage" section is blank. I noticed a related question that refers to "sensors" section being blank.  This is the fix for "sensors":
Hardinfo uses lm-sensors for the sensors section. To view anything here you need to first install lm-sensors.

`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

After that you will need to set up the sensors:

`sudo sensors-detect`

Just follow what it says. I always just trust it knows what it's doing and say yes to all the test, etc. Just make sure that you say yes to save it's findings, as it defaults to no. Now restart the sensors service:
`sudo service module-init-tools start`

Use the following command to see if it found valid sensors and you can use them:

`sensors`

Is this also the fix for "storage"?  If not what are the steps to resolve the issue?

Thank you.

Update, I ran the following in the commandline:
`$ hardinfo`
`Gtk-Message: 21:36:50.562: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.`

I researched the error and ran the following:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module`

I then ran:

`$ hardinfo`
`Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.`

So only part of the issue was fixed. I still have the above error and "storage" is still blank

Comment: How did you install hardinfo? apt will, for instance, also install lm-sensors as a dependency.

Comment: I can't locate the exact command in the history but this is how I normally install packages:  `sudo apt-get install -y hardinfo`

Comment: I just ran hardinfo in the command line: `$ hardinfo`
`Gtk-Message: 21:36:50.562: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.`

Comment: `hardinfo` works for me in 18.04.x and in 20.04.x. I see temperatures at 'Sensors' and I see specs for the drives at 'Storage'. Is there nothing at all or is there less than you expect? What do you see and what do you expect to see? You can upload a screenshot of `hardinfo` showing what you see at 'Storage' and render it as a picture by editing your original question.

Comment: What computer is it, brand name and model? Is your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS updated and upgraded (fully up to date)? Have you installed some special program package, that might disturb the update-upgrade process?

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron 3501.  I'm not seeing any errors when I update or upgrade.  I am also not sure what I should expect to see there.  Since my laptop has storage I was assuming that the fields should have some information in them like the sensors do

Comment: I have two Dell computers, one Latitude and and Precision, and they work well with Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS. But they are several years older than yours. Maybe you need the newest possible Ubuntu version in order for it to cooperate well with all of your hardware. So try live (from USB without installing with [Ubuntu 21.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/) which is a whole year newer, and the not yet released Impish Indri daily iso file from the [iso testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/) which will be released in October.

Comment: So actually I think it's working fine.  I viewed the /proc/cpuinfo file and there is a line called 'Flags' and it is very lengthy.  Since it's just a warning I'm gonna ignore it.  Thank you so much for your assistance. I'm not sure about the Storage issue though, that seems out of place, so I'm not sure quite where to go with it.

Comment: Thanks! I see, the info fields for 'Storage' are completely empty, and that is **wrong**. My best guess is that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is too old to recognize some parts of the hardware in your computer (as I wrote in the previous comment before noticing that you uploaded the screenshot).

Comment: Ah got it.  Thanks again

Comment: *It is also possible that the `hardinfo` program's software is too old*, while the other Ubuntu software is new enough in 20.04 LTS.

Comment: what's weird is that storage section seems to be the only section not functioning.  I tried some of those benchmark tests they function fine and even post results in the command line after I enter hardinfo in the terminal.  I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: If you are curious, you can try live (from USB without installing with Ubuntu 21.04 or even with Ubuntu Impish Indri as I described in a previous comment. (Install `hardinfo` into the live system only test if it works). You can also check with another tool, `lshw`  **l**i**s**t **h**ard**w**are which is bundled with Ubuntu: run in a terminal window `sudo lshw | less`

Comment: You can even try [a tool that we develop right now, `Report.sh`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465764&p=14054698#post14054698) to be used in the future to get information about hardware, to make it easier to help users at the Ubuntu Forums and here at AskUbuntu. -- In that case, copy and paste it from the box in the linked page to a text editor in your computer and save it to a file. Make the file executable and run it. You should get enough information about your storage hardware and how it is used.

Comment: You can always file a bug report against hardinfo to correct the issue if you feel that it should be showing your storage devices, which it should be.  `ubuntu-bug hardinfo`.  Also, looking at the bugs there isn't one filed for Storage not showing any devices.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hardinfo

Comment: So I just read your latest comments and I will try the report.sh first.  I do see this as a bug but my problem is why?  I have a feeling that the storage is reading from a location that has no information or the information is unreadable.  If it were otherwise I think that hardinfo would be trowing some type of error and it isn't.  The only error hardinfo throwing right now is related to 'Flags' in /proc/cpuinfo which is correct.  That field is chock full of strings and characters.

Comment: @sudodus- I don't have sufficient permissions to access the Report.sh.  I have never logged into the forum until now so I have no posts, etc.

Comment: @Terrance - I just submitted a bug report and included the link to this thread

Comment: So I looked at the actual flags in /proc/info.  There are indeed 897 characters in the file.  I have no idea why.  Another user reported in the bug that hardinfo reported fine and that he only had 100 characters in the "Flags".  Is there anyway to determine which flags should be there?  tried running the following but it didn't output anything: `$ egrep -wo ^flags|vmx|ept|vpid|npt|tpr_shadow|flexpriority|vnmi|lm|aes' /proc/cpuinfo --color | sort -u`
> ^C

Comment: Thanks to both TBr and Terrance, You are right, you have found a bug, and you have reported it too. I have confirmed it, clicked 'affects me too' :-) I wrote an answer in order to 1. Show a screenshot to confirm the bug; and 2. upload the tool that we develop right now, `Report.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my question.  HardInfo is a small application that displays information about your hardware and operating system. Currently it knows about PCI, ISA PnP, USB, IDE, SCSI, Serial and parallel port devices.
The Processor is Intel(R) Pentium(R) Gold 7505 @ 2.00GHz x 4  and the Storage device is an SSD, BC711 NVMe SK hynix(128GB).  I suspect hardinfo doesn't recognize the SSD and it doesn't like the extended flags in /proc/cpuinfo Otherwise hardinfo seems to function normally.  Please let me know if anyone has an SSD that is being recognized and I will keep digging.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Confirmed bug in `hardinfo`

You are right @TBr,

I checked in a computer with an NVMe SSD when running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and it recognizes a USB pendrive with a FAT32 partition seen as 'vfat' and a 'fake cdrom' (yes, it is part of the pendrive, there is no optical drive in the computer).

Hardinfo can see the content of the USB pendrive, but not the internal NVMe drive.

[image]

### Edit:

- I found your bug report and clicked on 'affects me too'.
- I noticed that you could not get the `Report.sh` from the Ubuntu Forums. There is no file to download yet, but I put a 'beta' version at the end of this edited answer. It should be possible to

  - copy and paste the whole text from the 'code' window with the script content to a text editor in your computer
  - save it with a suitable name, for example `Report.sh`
  - make it executable

    ```
    chmod +x Report.sh
    ```
  - run it in the directory where you store the script file

    ```
    ./Report.sh
    ```
  - read the file

    ```
    less '~/Report.txt'
    ```

#### Beta version of `Report.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

## MAFoElffen     2021.08.19
## Version 01.01, 2021.08.20
## Includes recommended changes submitted by:
##     sudodus    2021.08.20
##     oldfred    2021.08.20
## Filename: Report-01.01.sh
## Description: Report Finds Machine Hardware Related Information.
##     For support use at "UbuntuForums.org".

## Check if ran as root
if [[ "$EUID" == 0 ]]
   then echo "This script cannot be run as root"
   exit
fi

## Set filename and path to
report="$HOME/Report.txt"

## Set locale settings
LANG=C

## Set a pretty screen decoration for displaying the report onscreen
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

## Check for preinstalled prerequisites
REQUIRED=$(apt list --installed | grep inxi 2> /dev/null)
SUB1="installed"
boot_mode=$( [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "UEFI mode" || echo "Legacy mode (alias CSM alias BIOS mode)" )

echo "This script will install any prerequisite packages..." # The LiveCD has this preinstalled

if [[ $REQUIRED == *"$SUB1"* ]]; then
    continue;
else
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
    sudo apt install -y inxi;
fi

# User Input for Computer Make, Model, Type.
clear
echo -e "Please provide some \"Basic Information\"..."
#read -p "Computer Make (ie: Dell/HP/ASUS/Lenova): " computer_make
#read -p "Computer Model (ie: Ultima 420p) " computer_model
#read -p "Computer Type (ie: Server | Desktop | Laptop): " computer_type
read -p "What is the main complaint (summarized)? " main_complaint
read -p "Describe the Problem: " problem_description
clear

# Machine Info
echo -e "Starting Report: `date +%F`  `date +%T`" > $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- User Input:$resetvid" >> $report
#echo -e "Computer Make:  $computer_make" >> $report
#echo -e "Computer Model: $computer_model" >> $report
#echo -e "Computer Type:  $computer_type" >> $report
echo -e ""  >> $report
echo -e "Main Complaint: $main_complaint" >> $report
echo -e "Problem Description:  $problem_description" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- General computers specs from 'lshw':$resetvid" >> $report
sudo bash -c "lshw | sed '/*-core/,$ d'" >> $report
clear
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- General computers specs from 'inxi':$resetvid" >> $report
sudo bash -c "inxi -CDGimMoprS | grep -v 'loop\|snap'" >> $report
clear
echo -e "${blueback}---------- File System Disk Space Usage:$resetvid" >> $report
bash -c "df -h | grep -v '/snap/'" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Additional Disk/Partition Information:$resetvid" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Information From 'fdisk':$resetvid"  >> $report
sudo bash -c "fdisk -l | grep 'Disk\|Device\|/dev/' | grep -v 'loop\|snap'"  >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Information From 'lsblk':$resetvid"  >> $report
bash -c "lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,MODEL | grep -v '/snap/'" >> $report
echo -e "    ------- 'lsblk' information continued..." >> $report
bash -c "lsblk -o NAME,PARTUUID,UUID | grep -v loop" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Mount Details of '/etc/fstab':$resetvid"  >> $report
bash -c "egrep -v '#' /etc/fstab"  >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Video Details:$resetvid"  >> $report
sudo bash -c "lshw -C video" >> $report
clear
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "${blueback}---------- Other Details:$resetvid"  >> $report
echo -e "The computer boot mode was: $boot_mode" >> $report
echo -e "The current kernel version is: `uname -r`" >> $report
echo -e "The current release description is: `lsb_release -sd`" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "The current logged in User is: `who`" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "The User\'s ID is: `id`" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "The current running DE is: $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "*** End Of Report ***"  >> $report
echo -e "" >> $report
echo -e "The Report can be found at '$report' and can be viewed with 'less'"
echo -e ""
echo -e ""
less -r $report
## Post-Process Report.txt to remove the extraneous ANSI characters sequences from the report text...
perl -i -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG]//g' $report
#sed -i 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG]//g' $report
```

Comment: @ sudodus - I just ran the Report.sh and man did it grab a lot of information.  Would you like me to post any of it?

Comment: @TBr, I suggest that you create a user ID at the Ubuntu Forums and when logged in take part in the discussions how to develop this tool. Unfortunately the [thread 'Inspired' started by MAFoElffen](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465764), which should be the right place to post your Result.txt is in an Ubuntu member-only forum. I'm sure you can help us with fresh eyes and suggest improvements, so I will ask if a moderator can move the thread to a forum where all logged in users can read and write posts.

Comment: Hi again @TBr :-) Now you should be able to read and write in the thread that I link to in the previous comment because oldfred has moved it to a suitable forum.